# Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.Collider2D to SmallEnemy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Can't wrap my head around this simple syntax error. I am new to unity and coding.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collider2D hitInfo)
{
    SmallEnemy smallEnemy = hitInfo.GetComponent<Collider2D>();    
    if(smallEnemy != null)
    {
        smallEnemy.DamageEnemy(damage);
    }
```

Comment: the error is correct.  You asked it for the collider not the smallenemy component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of small things.

1. OnCollisionEnter2D uses Collision2D and not collider2d. Collision2D allows you access to the incoming gameObject in the struct itself.
2. GetComponent function return the conponent of type X so if your looking to get SmallEnemy component you want to use that as the type GetComponent< SmallEnemy>()

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        SmallEnemy smallEnemy = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<SmallEnemy>();
        if (smallEnemy != null)
        {
            smallEnemy.DamageEnemy(damage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explaining it, now I understand why it pulls up an error.